# Implementing submit event in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How do I get the data of a form upon clicking the a submit type button like so:

```
var x = form_submit.username;
var y = form_submit.password;
var z = form_submit.full_name;
```

and also stop the form from disappearing upon clicking the "Submit" button with the code below?

```
<form id="form_submit">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
<table>
  <tr>
      <th align="left">Full Name</th><td><input type="text" id="full_name" required></td>
  </tr>
  <!--<tr>
      <th align="left">Username</th><td><input type="text" id="username" required></td>
  </tr>-->
  <tr>
      <th align="left">Password</th><td><input type="password" id="full_name" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th align="left">Confirm Password</th><td><input type="password" id="confirm_password" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th align="left">Department</th><td><input type="text" id="department" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">Supervisor</th>
    <td>
      <select id="supervisor">
        <? for(var i in supervisors){ ?>
          <option value="<?=supervisors[i] ?>"><?=supervisors[i]?></option>
        <?}?>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th align="left">E-mail Address</th><td><input type="email" id="email" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Create Account" id='btn_create'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CSS').getContent(); ?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_submit').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var username = $('input[name="username"]', this).val();
      alert(username);
    });
  });
  }
</script>
```

I'm guessing that I should be using the "event.preventDefault()" method but I don't know where to place it.

P.S. I am using Google Sites, if it would make any difference. Thank you.

P.P.S.
  Edited my post to show the right answer.

Comment: If I were You I'd try using Ajax on forms. Here are some good sites to get you started: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form and the Ajax official site also: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ Don't get me wrong but there are many ways to work with forms. Ajax, based on my opinion and your tags, is the easiest solution for you to check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It will me help me. The problem is I am implementing this on Google Sites so not all requirements of Ajax can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something as simple as that - it seems to be working - perhaps it will fit your needs

**update:**

From what I checked you can address the form children easily if you give them id. for example you can currently do form_submit.children.username and get the value. if you will put IDs also on all the other tags like table, tr, th, etc. you will be able to dig deeper

**var form_submit = document.getElementById("form_submit");**

**var username = form_submit.children.username.value;**

**update 2:**

I`ve moved the script to the bottom of the body tag so I could get refernce to the submit button. Once got the button I registered to the "click" event using addEventListener. Now the PreventDefault method worked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form_submit">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Full Name</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="full_name" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Password</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" id="full_name" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Confirm Password</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" id="confirm_password" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Department</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="department" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">Supervisor</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">E-mail Address</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" id="email" required/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Account" id='btn_create'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>

            var button = document.getElementById("btn_create");
            if (button)
                button.addEventListener('click', createAccount, false);

            function createAccount(evt){
                var form_submit = document.getElementById("form_submit");
                var isValid = form_submit.checkValidity();
                alert('isValid: ' + isValid);
                var username = form_submit.children.username.value;
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can actually do it like that but what I am aiming at is if it is possible to get it like an object. Like this: var x = form_submit.username; and also stop the form from disappearing upon submit.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 From what I checked you can address the form children easily if you give them id. for example you can currently do form_submit.children.username and get the value. if you will put IDs also on all the other tags like table, tr, th, etc. you will be able to dig deeper.
I updated the question to hold this data

Comment: I'll try that. One thing though, you placed "return false" would that make the form elements not disappear?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 no, I tried that and the form data still disappear. I`ll continue searching for something

Comment: I think it needs the evt.preventDefault(); I just don't know how to iplement it on this code.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Nailed it. - I moved the script to the bottom of the html so I could register the event listener of the click. Once I did that the 'PreventDefault' method did its job properly.
Enjoy :)

Comment: It actually does the trick but the problem is, if you notice on my tags it has the attribute of required which should fire up when I click on the button submit. In the code you gave me the "require checking" does not fire up. Meaning, even if you submit the form and the input fields are blank, it still submits. I have the answer and it is in my edit :-D. I would still mark this post as the answer since it did the trick though not all of it. Thank you so much for the time.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 This is the down side of the PreventDefault method - it doesnt call the validation on the fields. The only solution is to manually check the form like this `var isValid = form_submit.checkValidity()` and then style the fields which are invalid with red border, again manually.
Or simply find some library which does that (can`t think of one now).

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the form to actually been submitted and process the data, you must cancel the event by returning `false` in your called function, pay special attention that you need to use the return statement in your onClick parameter.

`onclick="createAccount(this.parentNode)"`

=>

`onclick="return createAccount(this.parentNode)"`

```js
  function createAccount(frmData){
alert(document.getElementById("form_submit").elements.namedItem("username").value);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: I did as you suggested. It still disappears on submit and can you please show me how to get the values of the form on submit like this: var x = form_submit.username;